# Problem with a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a problem with this small program. It added some value to list. If I uncomment  `//printf("%d",first->val);` the program gives error. Everything seems to be ok ;(

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 typedef struct element {
   struct element *next;
   int val;
 } el_listy;

el_listy *first = 0;


void add_to_list(el_listy *lista, int value)
{

 if(lista == 0)
    {
        lista = malloc (sizeof(el_listy));
        lista->val = value;
        lista->next = 0;
        printf("added as first \n");
    }
        else
        { printf("added as fsecond  \n");
    el_listy *wsk = lista,*tmp;

                while(wsk->next != 0) wsk = wsk->next;

                tmp = malloc (sizeof(el_listy));
                tmp->val = value;
                tmp->next = 0;  

                wsk->next = tmp;                    
        }
}

 int main ()
 {
         add_to_list(first,2);
            add_to_list(first,4);
            //printf("%d",*first->val);
            system("pause");
   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`first->val` is just like `(*first).val`, you can't use them both. also, as missingno said, `add_to_list` never changes `first` you should pass it's address as argument, not the pointer itself, meaning`add_to_list(&first,4);` (and change the implementation of `add_to_list` as well)

Answer (score 2):

Your program never changes the value of `first`. It remains a null pointer and thus gives an error when dereferenced.

Answer (score 1):

`->` already follows a pointer, so the `*` tries to treat `first` as pointer to pointer to `el_listy`.  You might find [`cdecl`](http://www.cdecl.org/) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should use either `(*first).val` or `first->val`. Otherwise you get the wrong level of indirection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a simple mistake.

*fitsr* won't change after *add_to_list()* function is called.

You should define function like this:

```
add_to_list(El_list **lista, ...)
```